# JDBC, connection is ok but does not execute query

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I'm writing a small program with a mysql connection. I have to insert data into the database. The connection is ok but when I try to execute a query it doesn't work. all statements after executeQuery() statement doesn't work.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Connection connect=null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql//localhost/jarvis";
    String USER = "test";
    String PASS = "test";
    try{
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        out.println("Errore: "+e);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Prova.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    out.println();
    out.println("qui");
    String query = "INSERT INTO users(Nome, Cognome, Username, Password) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try (PreparedStatement insert = connect.prepareStatement(query)) {

        insert.setString(1, "name");
        insert.setString(2, "sur");
        insert.setString(3, "gvhgv");
        insert.setString(4, "qfwe");

        insert.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        out.println("Errore "+e);
    }
    out.println("Fine");


}
```

on executeQuery it stop working and doesn't insert the values into the database.

P.S.: sorry for my English
[foto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze372.png)

Comment: check the error message, ensure your user has the grant to make insertions to the specified target.

Comment: can you execute this manually an it works?

Comment: There must be an exception thrown @ `stmt.executeQuery`.

Comment: yes the query works in mysql standalone but it doesn't work in the program. How can I see error message? i'm using netbeans

Comment: Try using `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`. Also add a commit.

Comment: yes the user has all privileges

Comment: executeUpdate doesn't work too

Comment: Also look into using `PreparedStatement`

Comment: I also used prepared statement but it doesn't work i tried a lot of type of methods but it even crash on the query execution

Comment: _stop working_ doesn't help us help you.  Post the exception stack trace.

Comment: this is the exception: java.lang.NullPointerException but now i used preparedStatement

Comment: MMMh... My two cents are that `connect` is `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your JDBC Connection URL is wrong, it should be this

```
String DB_URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost/jarvis
```

instead of this:

```
String DB_URL = jdbc:mysql//localhost/jarvis
```

You can follow the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) whenever you are in doubt about anything.

Please note that mentioning port is not necessary if it is skipped it would default to MySQL's default port 3306.

Secondly, use `executeUpdate()` method instead of `executeQuery` method. It is best suggested to test your code in chunks, like DB Connection is successful, able to retrieve data from the underlying DB and then inserting into the DB.

Or even a better way is to debug your code and at least provide where you find the `NullPointerException` as you say you're getting now!

***Edit:***

You must have your JDBC Connector/J jar available for your code to access it if you use an IDE (then in its build path) and in the CLASSPATH global variable (for references when we don't use an IDE). It is better to have it on your CLASSPATH if you are not going to change these dependencies any often.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The port is optional in the url, so `jdbc:mysql://localhost/jarvis` (with colon after `mysql`, without port) is also valid.

Comment: Yes @MarkRotteveel, I did mention that in my answer!

Comment: The problem I see is that it detracts from the real problem: it is easy to overlook that single colon if there is another 5 character difference.

Comment: @francescopioGaglione, is your problem solved with the answer!